# Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability in C

Tags: c, security, url, remote-file-inclusion, file-inclusion

Hope your doing well.
Can somebody help me to resolve this. Cross-Site Scripting in C.
This is occurring in my C file.

Here am proving the URL like, how they are getting the info.

```
http://rs152.mt.att.com:8001/cgi-bin/rep_gtlsts?f_srep2.ht=<script>alert(261)</script>
```

Here what's happening is hacker are trying to edit the URL and injecting the alert. When i try to execute the URL am getting 261 popup alert. I need to resrtict the URL.
Am adding file here i.e., rep_gtlsts.C file.
I have added libary file also, Still it is not working that means still am getting popup.

```
#ifndef NOWHAT
#include "TNccidtab.h"

#define MAXKWS  100
#define WGDATAFILE  "wglist"

char * cp;
char * empty = "<empty>";
char input[] = "../../../../../../../../../etc/password";
#define safenv(a)   ((cp=getenv(a)) ? cp : empty)

/* Define all global variables: */
int allstreamFlag=0;                               //declared by santosh
void easy_prt_out();

/* Declare all local functions defined in this file: */

int
main(int argc, char **argv){
    int     i,j,num_cllis;
    int     ret;
    char    *qs;
    char    delim;
    char    copyqs[200];
    //int abc=0;
    eSetFyi(0);
    argc = eInit(argc,argv);
    eTrace('d',("in rep main"));
    /* add callbacks for rules messaging */
    eMapMsg(rule_ds1es);
    eMapMsg(rule_rtn);
    eMapMsg(rule_ecsps);
    eMapMsg(rule_rdted);
    eMapMsg(rule_toos);
    eMapMsg(r_ps_rules);
    ent = gethostbyname("nicprimary");
    cout << "Content-type:  text/html" << endl << endl;
    uname(&utname);

    if (!getClientID(clientID)) { 
        cout << "<HTML>" << endl;
        cout << "<BODY>" << endl;
        cout << "Security Violation:  error obtaining clientID" << endl;
        cout << "</HTML>" << endl;
        cout << "</BODY>" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    if ((qs = getenv("QUERY_STRING")) == NULL) {
        cout << "<HTML>" << endl;
        cout << "<BODY>" << endl;
        cout << "No query information to decode." << endl;
        cout << "</HTML>" << endl;
        cout << "</BODY>" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
char* clearUrl(char* input) {
    char* output = input;
    while (1) {
        if (*output == '/')
            output ++;
        else if (!strncmp(output, "~/", 2))
            output += 2;
        else if (!strncmp(output, "./", 2))
            output += 2;
        else if (!strncmp(output, "../", 3))
            output += 3;
        else
            break;
    }
    return output;
}
 printf("Cleaned QUERY_STRING: %s\n", clearUrl(input));
    allstreamFlag = isAllstreams(clientID);  //Added by santosh
    strcpy(copyqs,qs);
    for(i=0; qs[i] && ((qs[i]!='&' && qs[i] != '+')); i++) {
        html_file[i] = qs[i];
    }
    no_g2_call = 1;
    rule_acc = 0;
    owner_idx = 0;
    html_file[i] = '\0';
    unescape_url(html_file);
    if (strcmp(html_file,qs) != 0) {
        delim = qs[i];
        i++;
        qs = &qs[i]; 
        if (delim == '+') {
            /* parse out keyword*/
            strcpy(kword,qs);
            unescape_url(kword);
            if (kword[0] == '\0') {
                cout << "<HTML>" << endl;
                cout << "<BODY>" << endl;
                cout << "No valid keyword entered " << endl;
                cout << "</HTML>" << endl;
                cout << "</BODY>" << endl;
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else if (delim == '&') {
            for (i=0; qs[0] != '\0'; i++ ) {
                splitword(elements[i].val, qs, '&');
                unescape_url(elements[i].val);
                splitword(elements[i].name, elements[i].val, '=');
                if (strcmp(elements[i].name,"fdsig") == 0) { 
                    strncpy(parms.desig,elements[i].val,MAX_DESIG_LEN);
                    parms.desig[MAX_DESIG_LEN] = '\0';
                }
                else if (strcmp(elements[i].name,"ftype") == 0) { 
                    strncpy(parms.type,elements[i].val,MAX_TYPE_LEN);
                    parms.type[MAX_TYPE_LEN] = '\0';
                }
                if (strcmp(elements[i].name,"btfn") == 0) {
                    strncpy(parms.btfn,elements[i].val,MAX_TFN_LEN);
                    parms.btfn[MAX_TFN_LEN] = '\0';
                }
                if (strcmp(elements[i].name,"ttm") == 0) {
                    strncpy(parms.ttm,elements[i].val,MAX_TTM_LEN);
                    parms.ttm[MAX_TTM_LEN] = '\0';
                else if (strcmp(elements[i].name,"rule_type") == 0) {
                    strncpy(parms.rule_type,elements[i].val,MAX_RULE_TYPE_LEN);
                    parms.rule_type[MAX_RULE_TYPE_LEN] = '\0';
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
    sprintf(file_path,"../htdocs/%s",html_file);
    eTrace('d',("%s file_path",file_path));
    eTrace('d',("%s html file",html_file));
    /* set array of configurations to null before you load it */
    read_cllis = 1;
    for (i=0;i<MAXKWS;i++) {
        memset((void *)&conf_array[i],'\0',sizeof(DCONF));
    }
    if (strcmp(html_file,"ec_eqf.htm") == 0) {
        cout << copyqs << endl;
    }

    if (strcmp(html_file,"f_srep2.ht") == 0 || strcmp(html_file,"f_srep3.ht") == 0 ) { //added the checking for f_srep3.ht for Allstream project
        read4ecllis();
        read5ecllis();
        readDmscllis();
        readttms();
        readccids();
        num_kws = 0; 
        kwdata(REPREAD,clientID,&num_kws);
        nic_name = TNgetfullname("nicprimary");
        if(nic_name == NULL) {
            cout << "<HTML>" << endl;
            cout << "<BODY>" << endl;
            cout << "Full name for nicprimary not found." << endl;
            cout << "</BODY>" << endl;
            cout << "</HTML>" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }

    }
    if ((strcmp(html_file,"r_resp.ht")== 0) || (strcmp(html_file,"r_sched.ht")== 0)){
        how_to_respond = atoi(parms.resp_type);
        strcpy(err_msg,parms.nicerr);
        switch (how_to_respond) {
            case 0:
                result = atoi(parms.result);
                if (result == 0) {
                    strcpy(respond_type,"Accepted Successfully");
                }
                else {
                    strcpy(respond_type,"NOT Accepted");
                }
                // reset result cause not a nic error here
                result = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                result = sched_rule(parms.rule_name,parms.cig_name,atoi(parms.priority),atoi(parms.rule_type));
                break;
            case 2:
                result = act_rule(parms.rule_name,parms.cig_name,atoi(parms.rule_type),RACT);
                break;
            case 3:
                result = act_rule(parms.rule_name,parms.cig_name,atoi(parms.rule_type),RDACT);
                break;
            case 4:
                result = del_rule(parms.rule_name,parms.cig_name,atoi(parms.rule_type));
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Error in Action Type" << endl;
                break;
        }
        if (result < 0) {   
            /* put out error message */
            cout << "<HTML>" << endl;
            cout << "<BODY>" << endl;
            cout << "Error Sending to NIC" << endl;
            cout << "</HTML>" << endl;
            cout << "</BODY>" << endl;
            eExit(0);
        }
    }
    if (strcmp(html_file,"rulesadm.ht") == 0) {
        /* get list of 4e cllis for main page */
        read4ecllis();
        read5ecllis();
        readDmscllis();
        readttms();
        kwdata(REPREAD,clientID,&num_kws);
        nic_name = TNgetfullname("nicprimary");
        if(nic_name == NULL) {
            cout << "<HTML>" << endl;
            cout << "<BODY>" << endl;
            cout << "Full name for nicprimary not found." << endl;
            cout << "</BODY>" << endl;
            cout << "</HTML>" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if ((strcmp(html_file,"r_rdtexpi.ht") == 0) ||
        (strcmp(html_file,"r_rdtexp.ht") == 0) ||
        readttms();
    }
    if ((strcmp(html_file,"ds1_8_d.htm") == 0) ||
        (strcmp(html_file,"tsg_8_d.htm") == 0)) {
        readccids();
    }
    if ((strcmp(html_file,"4ecllis.htm") == 0) ||
        (strcmp(html_file,"sellist1.ht") == 0)) {
            read4ecllis();
    }
    if ( strcmp(html_file,"asellist1.ht") == 0)
    {
        readAllstream4ecllis();
    }
    if ( strcmp(html_file,"arepconfl.ht") == 0)
    {
        readAllstream4ecllis();
        num_kws = 0;
        kwdata(REPREAD,clientID,&num_kws);
        kw_idx = matchkw(kword,num_kws);
    }
    if (strcmp(html_file,"sellist5.ht") == 0) {
            read4ecllis();
    }
    if ((strcmp(html_file,"list_rules.ht") == 0) ||
        (strcmp(html_file,"lstrlpwl.ht") == 0)) {
        eTrace('d',("in if for list rules"));
        tbl_rows = get_prules();
    }
    if (strcmp(html_file,"r_ds1es.ht") == 0) {
        how_to_respond = atoi(parms.resp_type);
        if (how_to_respond == 0) {
                result = add_rule(atoi(parms.rule_type));
        }
        else {
            rule_acc = get_r_ds1es(parms.rule_name,parms.cig_name);
        }
    }
    if (strcmp(html_file,"r_rtnexp.ht") == 0) {
        how_to_respond = atoi(parms.resp_type);
        if (how_to_respond == 0) {
                result = add_rule(atoi(parms.rule_type));
        }
        else {
            rule_acc = get_r_rtn(parms.rule_name,parms.cig_name);
        }
    }
    if (strcmp(html_file,"r_ecscan.ht") == 0) {
        how_to_respond = atoi(parms.resp_type);
        if (how_to_respond == 0) {
                result = add_rule(atoi(parms.rule_type));
        }
        else {
            rule_acc = get_r_ecscan(parms.rule_name,parms.cig_name);
        }
    }
    if (strcmp(html_file,"r_rdtexp.ht") == 0) {
        how_to_respond = atoi(parms.resp_type);
        if (how_to_respond == 0) {
                result = add_rule(atoi(parms.rule_type));
        }
        else {
            rule_acc = get_r_rdtexp(parms.rule_name,parms.cig_name);
        }
    }
    if (strcmp(html_file,"r_trkoos.ht") == 0) {
        how_to_respond = atoi(parms.resp_type);
        if (how_to_respond == 0) {
                result = add_rule(atoi(parms.rule_type));
        }
        else {
            rule_acc = get_r_trkoos(parms.rule_name,parms.cig_name);
        }
    }
    if ((strcmp(html_file,"drdtd.ht") == 0) || (strcmp(html_file,"rtnexp.ht") == 0)) {
            readttms();
    }
    if ((strcmp(html_file,"eds1_es.ht") == 0) || (strcmp(html_file,"aeds1_es.ht") == 0) ||
        (strcmp(html_file,"etsg_es.ht") == 0) || (strcmp(html_file,"aetsg_es.ht") == 0)) {
            readttms();
            readtucs();
            mcn_feature=isAllowed("ssimcnfltr");
            if(allstreamFlag==1)
            {
                mcn_feature=0;
            }
            if (mcn_feature) LoadMcnData();
            
    }
    if (strcmp(html_file,"repconfl.ht") == 0) {
        read4ecllis();
        num_kws = 0;
        kwdata(REPREAD,clientID,&num_kws);
        kw_idx = matchkw(kword,num_kws);
    }
    if (strcmp(html_file,"repconfl5.ht") == 0) {
        read4ecllis();
        read5ecllis();
        readDmscllis();
        num_kws = 0;
        kwdata(REPREAD,clientID,&num_kws);
        kw_idx = matchkw(kword,num_kws);
    }
    if (strcmp(html_file,"reprmv.ht") == 0) {
        num_kws = 0;
        kwdata(REPREAD,clientID,&num_kws); 
        kw_idx = matchkw(kword,num_kws);
        if (kw_idx >= 0) {
            if (num_kws == 1) {
                memset((void *)&conf_array[0],'\0',sizeof(DCONF));
            }
            else {
                for (i=kw_idx+1;i<num_kws;i++){
                    conf_array[i-1] = conf_array[i];
                }
            }
        }
        num_kws = num_kws - 1;
        kwdata(REPWRITE,clientID,&num_kws);
    }
    if (strcmp(html_file,"repsave.ht") == 0) {
        num_kws = 0;
        kwdata(REPREAD,clientID,&num_kws); 
        kw_idx = matchkw(kword,num_kws);
        for (i=0;i<200;i++){
            conf_array[kw_idx].cllis[i][0] = '\0';
        }
        ret = read_post(&num_cllis);
        strcpy(conf_array[kw_idx].kw,kword);
        if (num_cllis > 200) {
            num_cllis = 200;
        }
        for (i=0;i<num_cllis;i++) {
            strcpy(conf_array[kw_idx].cllis[i],elements[i].val);
        }
        if (num_kws == kw_idx) {
            num_kws = kw_idx + 1;
        }
        kwdata(REPWRITE,clientID,&num_kws);
    }
    if ((strcmp(html_file,"ds1_8_d.htm") == 0) ||
        (strcmp(html_file,"ads1_8_d.htm") == 0) ||
        LoadWorkGroupList();
    }
    if (no_g2_call) {
        easy_prt_out();
    }
    else {
        eTrace('d',("before eGo"));
        eGo();
    }
}

void easy_prt_out() {
    char    buf[8192];  
    char    left[128];  
    char    right[128]; 
    int     i,j;
    int     count = 0;
    int corbaccess ;
    eTrace('d',("file_path %s",file_path));
    ifstream inp_rep(file_path);
            
    if(!inp_rep) {
        cout << "<HTML>" << endl;
        cout << "<BODY>" << endl;
        cout << "cannot open file " << html_file << endl;
        cout << "</BODY>" << endl;
        cout << "</HTML>" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while(inp_rep.getline(buf,sizeof(buf))){
        if(strstr(buf,"{$CLLIARRAY}")) {
                strsplit(buf,"{$CLLIARRAY}",left,right);
            cout << "var " << left << "=new Array(" << numCllis <<")\n" << endl;
                for(i=0; i<numCllis; i++) {
                cout << left << "[" << i <<"]=" << left << "['" << abbrev[i] << "']='" << clliarray[i] << "'\n" <<endl;
            }
            cout << "// end of 4e" << endl;
            right[0] = '\0';
            }
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$CLLI5ARRAY}")) {
            cout << "// beg of 5e" << endl;
                strsplit(buf,"{$CLLI5ARRAY}",left,right);
            cout << "var " << left << "=new Array(" << num5Cllis <<")\n" << endl;
                for(i=0; i<num5Cllis; i++) {
                cout << left << "[" << i <<"]=" << left << "['" << abbrev5[i] << "']='" << clli5array[i] << "'\n" <<endl;
            }
            right[0] = '\0';
            } 
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$CLLIDARRAY}")) {
            cout << "// beg of Dms" << endl;
                strsplit(buf,"{$CLLIDARRAY}",left,right);
            cout << "var " << left << "=new Array(" << numDCllis <<")\n" << endl;
                for(i=0; i<numDCllis; i++) {
                cout << left << "[" << i <<"]=" << left << "['" << abbrevD[i] << "']='" << clliDarray[i] << "'\n" <<endl;
            }
            right[0] = '\0';
            }
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$CCIDS}")) {
            cout << "// beg of ccids" << endl;
            strsplit(buf,"{$CCIDS}",left,right);
            sprintf(buf,"var %s=new Array(%d);\n",left,numccids);
            cout << "var " << left << "=new Array(" << numccids <<")\n" << endl;
            for(i=0; i<numccids; i++) {
                cout << left << "[" << i <<"]='" << ccids[i] << "'\n" <<endl;
            }
            right[0] = '\0';
        }
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$MENU}")) {
            strsplit(buf,"{$MENU}",left,right);
            if (isAllowed("ISC")) {
                cout << left << "/menuint.htm" << right << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << left << "/menu1.htm" << right << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$FOURORFIVE}")) {
            strsplit(buf,"{$FOURORFIVE}",left,right);
            if (isAllowed("ISC")) {  
                if (allstreamFlag == 1)
                    cout << left << "/cgi-bin/rep_gtlsts?arepconfl.ht" << right << endl;
                else
                    cout << left << "/cgi-bin/rep_gtlsts?repconfl.ht" << right << endl;
            }
            else {
                if (allstreamFlag == 1)
                    cout << left << "/cgi-bin/rep_gtlsts?arepconfl.ht" << right << endl;
                else
                    cout << left << "/cgi-bin/rep_gtlsts?repconfl5.ht" << right << endl;
            }
                
        }
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$SEL4OR5}")) {
            strsplit(buf,"{$SEL4OR5}",left,right);
             if (isAllowed("ISC") ) {
                if(allstreamFlag == 1) //A new ht file (asellist1.ht) is created for allstream users
                    cout << left << "/cgi-bin/rep_gtlsts?asellist1.ht" << right << endl;
                else
                    cout << left << "/cgi-bin/rep_gtlsts?sellist1.ht" << right << endl;
            }
            else {
                if(allstreamFlag == 1) //A new ht file (asellist1.ht) is created for allstream users
                    cout << left << "/cgi-bin/rep_gtlsts?asellist1.ht" << right << endl;
                else
                    cout << left << "/cgi-bin/rep_gtlsts?sellist5.ht" << right << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$RMENU}")) {
            strsplit(buf,"{$RMENU}",left,right);
            if (isAllowed("ISC")) {
                cout << left << "/rmenuint.htm" << right << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << left << "/rmenu1.htm" << right << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$MCNTITLE}")) {
            if (mcn_feature) {
                cout << "<TD colspan=2 align=center ><B>MCN</B></TD>"   << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "<input type='hidden' name='mcn' value=''>" << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (strstr(buf,"{$MCNLIST}")) {
            if (mcn_feature) getMcnList() ;
        }
        else if (strstr(buf,"{$4ECLLIS}")){
            /* found my marker to insert the 4eclli list */
                    for(i=0; i<numCllis; i++) {
                cout << "<OPTION>" << clliarray[i] << "</OPTION>" <<endl;
                    }
            }
            else if (strstr(buf,"{$4EACLLIS}")){
            /* found my marker to insert the 4eclli list */
                    for(i=0; i<numCllis; i++) {
                cout << "<OPTION>" << clliAarray[i] << "</OPTION>" <<endl;
                    }
            }
        else if (strstr(buf,"{$5ECLLIS}")){
            /* found my marker to insert the 5eclli list */
                    for(i=0; i<num5Cllis; i++) {
                cout << "<OPTION>" << clli5array[i] << "</OPTION>" <<endl;
                    }
            }
        else if (strstr(buf,"{$DMSCLLIS}")){
            /* found my marker to insert the Dmsclli list */
                    for(i=0; i<numDCllis; i++) {
                cout << "<OPTION>" << clliDarray[i] << "</OPTION>" <<endl;
                    }
            }
        /****************************************************/
        /*                  RULE SCREENS                    */
        /****************************************************/
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$RTRKOOS}")) {
            /* print out the data structure of the rule */
            pr_trk_rule();
        }
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$ACC}")) {
            strsplit(buf,"{$ACC}",left,right);
            if (rule_acc == 0) {
                /* rule has been accepted because we have data */   
                cout << left << "Y" << right << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << left << "N" << right << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$SCHED}")) {
            strsplit(buf,"{$SCHED}",left,right);
            if (r_ds1es.app_time[0] != '\0') {
                /* rule has been scheduled because we have data */  
                cout << left << "Y" << right << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << left << "N" << right << endl;
            }
        }
        }
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$RULEARRAY}")) {
            strsplit(buf,"{$RULEARRAY}",left,right);
            cout << "var " << left << " = new Array()" << endl;
            for (i=0;i<rule_data_cnt;i++) {
                cout << left << "[" << i << "]=new Array('"<<rule_data[i].rule_name ;
                cout << "'," << endl << "'" << rule_data[i].cig_name;
                if (strcmp(rule_data[i].rule_type,"ds1_es") == 0) {
                    cout << "'," << endl << "'" << "0";
                }
                if (strcmp(rule_data[i].rule_type,"rtn") == 0) {
                    cout << "'," << endl << "'" << "4";
                }
                else if (strcmp(rule_data[i].rule_type,"rdt_ed") == 0) {
                    cout << "'," << endl << "'" << "2";
                }
                cout << "');" << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (strstr(buf,"{$ADDROW}")){
            /* found my marker to insert the table rows*/
            cout << "<tr>" <<endl;
            inp_rep.getline(buf,sizeof(buf));

            if (rule_data_cnt > 0) {
                /* put out first row of the table and save the structure of */
                /* on screen table to output subsequent rows */
                ch_row_idx = 0;
                while (!strstr(buf,"{$ENDROW}")){
                    if (strstr(buf,"{$RULE_NAME}")){
                        strsplit(buf,"{$RULE_NAME}",row_left.rule_name,row_right.rule_name);
                        cout << row_left.rule_name << " " << rule_data[0].rule_name << row_right.rule_name <<endl;
                    }
                    else if (strstr(buf,"{$PRIORITY}")){
                        strsplit(buf,"{$PRIORITY}",row_left.priority,row_right.priority);
                        cout << row_left.priority << " " << rule_data[0].priority << row_right.priority <<endl;
                    }
                    else if (strstr(buf,"{$DESCRIP}")){
                        strsplit(buf,"{$DESCRIP}",row_left.descrip,row_right.descrip);
                        if (strcmp(rule_data[0].descrip,"") == 0) {
                            // no description so make sure a space is there
                            // so frame of box shows up correctly
                            cout << row_left.descrip << "&nbsp" << rule_data[0].descrip << row_right.descrip <<endl;
                        }
                        else {
                            cout << row_left.descrip << " " << rule_data[0].descrip << row_right.descrip <<endl;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (strstr(buf,"{$SCHED}")){
                        strsplit(buf,"{$SCHED}",row_left.sched,row_right.sched);
                        cout << row_left.sched << " " << rule_data[0].sched << row_right.sched <<endl;
                    }
                    else if (strstr(buf,"{$STATE}")){
                        strsplit(buf,"{$STATE}",row_left.state,row_right.state);
                        cout << row_left.state << " " << rule_data[0].state << row_right.state <<endl;
                    else {
                        cout << buf << endl;
                        strcpy(checkrow[ch_row_idx],buf);
                        ch_row_idx++;
                    }
                    inp_rep.getline(buf,sizeof(buf));
                }
            }
            else {
                //no data so get endrow marker
                while (!strstr(buf,"{$ENDROW}")){
                    inp_rep.getline(buf,sizeof(buf));
                }
            }
            if (!strstr(buf,"{$ENDROW}")){
                cout << "HTML file error" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "</tr>" <<endl;
            }
            /* Now continue and put out subsequent table rows */
            for(i=1; i<rule_data_cnt; i++) {
                cout << "<tr>" <<endl;
                cout << checkrow[0]<<endl;
                cout << checkrow[1]<<endl;
                cout << checkrow[2]<<endl;
                cout << row_left.rule_name << " " << rule_data[i].rule_name << row_right.rule_name <<endl;
                cout << row_left.priority << " " << rule_data[i].priority << row_right.priority <<endl;
                if (strcmp(rule_data[i].descrip,"") == 0) {
                    // no description so make sure a space is there
                    // so frame of box shows up correctly
                    cout << row_left.descrip << "&nbsp" << row_right.descrip <<endl;
                }
                else {
                    cout << row_left.descrip << " " << rule_data[i].descrip << row_right.descrip <<endl;
                }
                cout << row_left.sched << " " << rule_data[i].sched << row_right.sched <<endl;
                cout << row_left.state << " " << rule_data[i].state << row_right.state <<endl;
                cout << row_left.accepted << " " << rule_data[i].accepted << row_right.accepted <<endl;
                cout << "</tr>" <<endl;
            }
        }
        else if (strstr(buf,"{$PASSPARMS}")){
            if (parms.level[0] != '\0') { 
                cout << "var level = '" << parms.level << "'"<< endl;
                if ((parms.level[0] == 'D') ||
                    (parms.level[0] == 'S') ||
                    (parms.level[0] == 'E') ||
                    (parms.level[0] == 'O')) {
                    /* DS1, DS3, E1, STS1, EC1, OC3, or EC */
                    if (parms.desig[0] == '\0') {
                        cout << "var p_desig = ''"<< endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "var p_desig = '" << parms.desig << "'" << endl;
                    }
                    if (parms.type[0] == '\0') {
                        cout << "var p_type = ''"<< endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "var p_type = '" << parms.type <<  "'" << endl;
                    }
                    if (parms.owner[0] == '\0') {
                        cout << "var p_owner = ''"<< endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "var p_owner = '" << parms.owner << "'" << endl;
                    }
                }
                else if (parms.level[0] == 'T') {
                    /* TSG */
                    if (parms.btfn[0] == '\0') {
                        cout << "var p_btfn = ''"<< endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "var p_btfn = '" << parms.btfn << "'" << endl;
                    }
                    if (parms.owner[0] == '\0') {
                        cout << "var p_owner = ''"<< endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "var p_owner = '" << parms.owner << "'" << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "var p_owner = '';"<< endl;
            }
        }
        else if (strstr(buf,"{$KEYWORDS}")){
            for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
                cout << "<OPTION>" << kwarr[i] << "</OPTION>" <<endl;
            }
        }
        else if (strstr(buf,"{$NICSERV}")){
            /* found my marker to insert fully qualified nic server name*/
            strsplit(buf,"{$NICSERV}",left,right);
            cout << left << nic_name << right <<endl;
            cout << "var allstreamFlag="<<allstreamFlag<<";" << endl;
       }
        else if (strstr(buf,"{$PARAM}")) {
          corbaccess=isAllowed("CORBAaccess") ;
          cout << "var corbaccess=" << corbaccess << ";" << endl;
        }
        else if (strstr(buf,"{$ALLSTREAMCLLI}")) {
          cout << "var allStreamCLLI" << "=new Array(" << MAXALLSTREAMCLLIS <<")\n" << endl;
          for(i=0;i<MAXALLSTREAMCLLIS;i++)
          {  
              cout<<"allStreamCLLI["<<i<<"]='" << ALLSTREAM_CLLIS[i] << "'" << ";" <<endl;
          }
          
        }

        else if (strstr(buf,"{$CONFID}")){
            strsplit(buf,"{$CONFID}",left,right);
            cout << left << kword << right <<endl;
            cout << left << kword << right <<endl;
        }
        else if (strstr(buf,"{$CONFARRAYUPD}")) {
            strsplit(buf,"{$CONFARRAYUPD}",left,right);
            if (num_kws > 0) {
                for (i=0;i<num_kws;i++) {
                    cout << left << "[" << i << "]=new Array('"<<conf_array[i].kw ;
                    
                    for(j=0; conf_array[i].cllis[j][0]; j++) {
                        cout << "'," << endl << "'" << conf_array[i].cllis[j];
                        
                    }
                    cout << "');" << endl;
                }
            }
            
        }
        else if(strstr(buf,"{$CONFARRAYLEN}")) {
            strsplit(buf,"{$CONFARRAYLEN}",left,right);
            if (num_kws < 0) {
                // no conf array elements currently existed
                num_kws = 0;
            }
            cout << left << num_kws << right <<endl;
        }
        else {
             cout << buf << endl;
        }
    }
    inp_rep.close();
}

int
mycmp(const char *s1, const char * s2) {
    return(strcmp(s1,s2));
}

void
read5ecllis() {
    int j;
    int matchCllis;

    if (read_cllis) {
        readcllis();
        read_cllis=0;
    }
    matchCllis = matchclli(NULL,clli5match,Clli5e);
    num5Cllis = 0;
    for (j=0; j<matchCllis; j++) {
        if (isCapable(OSPSSWITCH,clli5match[j]) || 
            isCapable(ADLSWITCH,clli5match[j])) {
            strcpy(clli5array[num5Cllis],clli5match[j]);
            if (is5eLocal(clli5match[j])) {                             /* MR000278 */
                find5eAbbrev(clli5match[j],NULL,abbrev5[num5Cllis]);
            }
            else {
                find5eAbbrev(clli5match[j],abbrev5[num5Cllis],NULL);
            }
            num5Cllis++;
        }
    }
}

void
readDmscllis() {
    int j;
    int matchCllis;

    if (read_cllis) {
            readcllis();
        read_cllis=0;
    }
        matchCllis = matchclli(NULL,clliDarray,ClliDMS);
    numDCllis = 0;
    for (j=0; j<matchCllis; j++) {
        if (isDMSLocal(clliDarray[j])) {                                /* MR000278 */
            findDMSAbbrev(clliDarray[j],NULL,abbrevD[numDCllis]);
        }
        else {
            findDMSAbbrev(clliDarray[j],abbrevD[numDCllis],NULL);
        }
        numDCllis++;
    }
}
void
readttms() {
    char *ptr, *filename, buf[128];
    int  cnt = 0;

    ptr = getenv(ETC_PATH);
    if(ptr == NULL)
        ptr = DEF_ETC_DIR;
    filename = findfile(ptr,"ttmtab",04);
    if(filename == NULL)
        return;
    ifstream inp(filename);

    if(!inp) {
        ERUNIX("fopen",filename);
        return;
    }
    while(inp.getline(buf,sizeof(buf))){
        if(buf[0] == '#')
            continue;
        ptr = strtok(buf,":");
        if(ptr)
            strcpy(ttmarray[cnt++],ptr);
        }
    ttmarray[cnt][0] = '\0';
    qsort((char *)ttmarray,cnt,sizeof(ttmarray[0]),entrycmp) ;
}
void
readccids() {

    char buffer [BUFFER_SZ], /* holds entry from CCID code file */
        *ptr ;               /* used to "parse" file entry */

    FILE *file_ptr ; /* file pointer to CCID code file */

    /*---------------------[ Executable Section ]-------------------*/

    numccids = 0 ;

    if ( ( file_ptr = openCcidFile () ) == NULL )
        return;
    while ( fgets ( buffer, sizeof ( buffer ), file_ptr ) != NULL && numccids
< MAX_CCID_CODES )
        {
        if ( ( ptr = strtok ( buffer, BLANK_MASK ) ) == NULL ||
              strchr ( ptr, COMMENT_CHAR )    != NULL ) /* skip comments
at top of file */
            continue ;

        strncpy ( ccids [numccids], strtoupper ( ptr ), CCID_LENGTH )
 ;
                  ccids [numccids][CCID_LENGTH] = '\0' ;

        numccids++ ;
        } /* end while */

    fclose ( file_ptr ) ;

    if ( numccids < 1 )
          return; /* no CCID codes found, nothing else to do */

    qsort ((char *) ccids, numccids, sizeof (ccids [0]), (int (*)(const void *,const void *))mycmp);
    return; /* everything must have worked if we're here ! */

}
int
sortkws(int count) 
{
int i;

    if (count != 0) {
        for(i=0;i<count;i++) {
            strcpy(kwarr[i], conf_array[i].kw);
            if(i == 100) {
                break;
            }
        }
        qsort(kwarr,count,20,(int (*)(const void *,const void *))mycmp);
    }
    return(count); 
}
```

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: It doesn't seem that you have actually asked a question. Can you please clarify what the problem or goal is?

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.. attackers are trying to get the data from etc/password file.. I should restrict the path and file.. 
actual URL : http://rs152.mt.att.com:8001/cgi-bin/rep_gtlsts?../docs/srp.ht
modified URL : http://rs152.mt.att.com:8001/cgi-bin/rep_gtlsts?../../../../../../../../../etc/password

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you want to make sure that local files that are in a parent directory cannot be accessed? Then all preceding `/` (make the path absolutely), `~/` (access the home directory), `../` (parent directory) and `./` (could hide the others) would have to be removed. In C it would be easiest to skip them. This can be done with the following code, for example:

```c
#include <string.h> // For strncmp
#include <stdlib.h> // For malloc

char* clearUrl(char* input) {
    // Part One: Remove occurrences at the beginning of the url
    // --------------------------------------------------------
    char* skippedStr = input;
    while (1) {
        if (*skippedStr == '/')
            skippedStr ++;
        else if (!strncmp(skippedStr, "~/", 2))
            skippedStr += 2;
        else if (!strncmp(skippedStr, "./", 2))
            skippedStr += 2;
        else if (!strncmp(skippedStr, "../", 3))
            skippedStr += 3;
        else
            break;
    }
    
    // Part Two: remove occurrences of /.. within the url
    // --------------------------------------------------
    char* output = (char*) malloc( (strlen(skippedStr)+1) * sizeof(char));
    
    char* cleanedStr = output;
    while (*skippedStr != '\0') {
        if (!strncmp(skippedStr, "/..", 3))
            skippedStr += 3;
        else {
            *cleanedStr = *skippedStr;
            cleanedStr++;
            skippedStr++;
        }
    }
    *cleanedStr = '\0'; // Append trailing null byte
    
    return output;
}
```

It should be noted that the procedure removes all `../` and does not check whether a directory is selected that should not be accessible. This could lead to unintended errors. An alternative would be to just search the URL and, if it contains `../` or similar, return a `400 Bad Request` to the client.

**Edit:** Thanks to Ian Abbott
for noting that occurrences of `/..` within the URL can also be dangerous. I had overlooked this and corrected the code accordingly.

---

**Edit after comment:**

To close the security hole, the code could be changed, for example, as follows:

```c
    // ...

    ent = gethostbyname("nicprimary");
    uname(&utname);

    if (!getClientID(clientID)) { 
        cout << "Content-type:  text/html" << endl << endl;
        cout << "<HTML>" << endl;
        cout << "<BODY>" << endl;
        cout << "Security Violation:  error obtaining clientID" << endl;
        cout << "</HTML>" << endl;
        cout << "</BODY>" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((qs = getenv("QUERY_STRING")) == NULL) {
        cout << "Content-type:  text/html" << endl << endl;
        cout << "<HTML>" << endl;
        cout << "<BODY>" << endl;
        cout << "No query information to decode." << endl;
        cout << "</HTML>" << endl;
        cout << "</BODY>" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    // This is the new security check about occurences of ../ within qs
    if (strstr(qs, "../")) {
        cout << "Status: 400 Bad Request" << endl << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    cout << "Content-type:  text/html" << endl << endl;

    // ...
```

This rejects all requests with a `400 Bad Request` in which `../` is contained in the query string. Note that

```c
cout << "Content-type:  text/html" << endl << endl;
```

must not be executed before the security check and has therefore been moved further down.

Comment: Wouldn't that be defeated by an input such as "foo/../../../../../../../../../../etc/password"? (As long as "foo" is known to be a valid directory.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, Can you help me how to write same code in c#??
And am getting below errors when am trying to compile.
```"../src/rep_gtlsts.C", line 311: Error: Use ";" to terminate declarations.
"../src/rep_gtlsts.C", line 325: Error: Cannot return char* from a function that should return int.
"../src/rep_gtlsts.C", line 1441: Warning: String literal converted to char* in assignment.
"../src/rep_gtlsts.C", line 1468: Warning: String literal converted to char* in assignment.
"../src/rep_gtlsts.C", line 3280: Warning: Implicit int is not supported in C++.
```

Comment: You add the file `rep_gtlsts.C` your question, which causes these error messages (only the noted lines)?

Comment: Thanks again, hope your safe...! I have added file, Can you please have a look..

Comment: What is stored in the variable `html_file`, so where was it declared? I assume it's a `char*`?

Comment: ```html_file``` is a variable contains all the required html file and it is declared like this  in the file ```char html_file[128];``` due size issues I can't able to add all of the code..

Comment: That is not necessary at the moment. I added some code about the security vulnerability to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you so much.. that is working very well.. Can please help me in this also for the same URL trying to inject or pass the value like this ```http://rs152.mt.att.com:8001/cgi-bin/rep_gtlsts?f_srep2.ht=<script>alert(261)</script>``` How can i avoid that ??

Comment: Coudl you maybe explain what the parameter causes to `f_srep2.ht`? Should there possibly be no parentheses `<` and `>`?

Comment: ```f_srep2.ht``` is a html file, that file is storing in a html_file variable. And am sorry I didn't get your point of parentheses.

Comment: @fcdt, Any suggestions plz??

Comment: Not really, at least I can't see where this input causes an popup alert (and also not how it is processed).

Comment: thank you.., Is there any way to restrict the URL path ??

Comment: @fcdt , am trying same way you suggested before
```if (strstr(qs, "<script>")) {
        cout << "Status: 400 Bad Request" << endl << endl;
        exit(0);```  it is not working here... don't know why...?!

Comment: You have ensured that nothing is output on `cout` before and the program is then ended immediately with `exit (0)`?